# Git: Pushing to bitbucket not asking for password

Tags: git

I created a repository on Bitbucket. Then I cloned it. Then on my side I made several commits and then.. pushed. And everything pushed successfully without asking for password. How could it be ?

Some things that could be important:

1. I have SourceTree program where my credentials are set.(But the bash thing is not a part of that program. It is a separate thing that I've downloaded).
2. I set global options via 'git config --global user.name ...'
3. The password for the account is set.

I heard that the password could be cached somehow, but I didn't make anything for that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you clone? Via http or ssh? If it is ssh this is normal because thats how ssh works? If http you might have hardcoded your credentials in .gitconfig file and then git uses this each time you push.

Comment: I cloned it via https. In .gitconfig there is my name and my email. Nothing about the password.

Comment: I have had this same thing happen to me and I'm quite intrigued. I do not have Sourcetree installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourcetree uses terminal/cli, and since your credentials are saved there, it uses them when you push

Comment: How I could check that ? Thank you.

Comment: Logout from sourcetree and try

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped. If you don't mind may I ask you a related question ? The password is asked via MSN window. Is it normal ? I thought it should be within the bash-window.

Comment: Depends on how you created you bitbucket account, but I'm not sure about it